# May I use a clean can opener previously used for non-kosher cans?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, appliances

It only had cold contact with treif, if any (only if the food reaches to top of the can); no duchka de sakina was involved.

Its contact with my kosher food is also cold - if any (only if the food reaches to top of the can).

Is it okay to use it?

Comment: Why do you say "no duchka de sakina was involved" "if the food reaches to top of the can"? If the can opener touches food, it because the cutting edge (that cuts into the can) cuts into the food, no?

Comment: Yes, okay to use.

Comment: @msh210: there is no _cutting_. "duchka de sakina" means knife pressing food to cut it. knife _touching_ food is  not "duchka de sakina".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [OU](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2007/kosher_food_in_a_non_kosher_office/) - it may be used after they are cleaned and rinsed off.

> Q. The lunch area in our office has a can opener, peeler,
>   bread-toaster (not a toaster oven), flatware, coffee mugs, glass
>   dishes and glass cups available for anyone to use. Can I use them? A.
>   The can opener and peeler can be used after they are cleaned or rinsed
>   off.